# Java Compiler Completed but Didn't Create the Executable?

Tags: java, api, cmd, compilation, compiler-warnings

(I am new to Java, I don't know what 'classes' or 'api's' are.)

I was trying to compile (`javac -g Sphinx.java`) this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;

public class Sphinx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter("status.txt"));
        LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
        recognizer.startRecognition(true);
        pw.print("running");
        SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
        pw.print("stopped");
        pw.close();

        PrintWriter pw2 = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter("result.txt"));
        pw2.println(result);
        pw2.close();
    }
}
```

And I got this message:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

So, I re-compiled with `-Xlint:deprecation`, like it told me to, and it didn't give me any errors this time, so I'm assuming the compiler was finished, and that it compiled successfully.

And then I look, and there's no .jar file, just a new .class file.

Now, I don't really know much about the java compiler, I was just told online that it would give me an executable for the code I had written, which in this case is a .jar file.

I don't know if the compiler sends newly created executables to a special system directory or what, but it's not here, and I don't know why.

Would someone more knowledgeable with Java please give me some context here.

Comment: *I was just told online that it would give me an executable*: whoever told you that doesn't know Java. Read good sources of information, like an introductory Java book, or the official Java tutorials

Comment: Always check documentation prior to question,
You need just add the next step - look at:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html



jar cf jar-file input-file(s)

Comment: @OleksandrBereziuk Could you put that into an answer, so I can accept it, please?

Comment: A .class file is also an executable if it contains a main method like yours do so I don't really understand why you need a jar.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Well, I didn't know that. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: A class file for a class with a suitable `main` method *is* an executable, at least as much as a jar file containing such a class is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just add the next step - look at: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

*jar cf jar-file input-file(s)*